# Draw a border for a selected window using .net

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Which WinAPI functions should I use to draw border on a selected window. For example, I make active any window by mouse (for example, notepad) and it should be framed by a border. How to implement it using .net?

Answer (score 0):

Use an function which will run when mouse is on the border that is `MouseHover` and inside that function define or draw border as your wish.

```
 //write an function like this
function()
{
  // do what you want some like this... or draw border
  selectedwindow.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

}

//then call it on MouseHover event.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is not appropriate if I want to frame by border any custom window, for example notepad.exe.

Comment: What you mean by notepad.exe? do you want to change another applications border from other application?

Comment: Do you want to make theme? Without theme i thnik it is not possible. Have you seen these kind of software before?

Comment: No, I do not want to make theme. What about possibility, I found a temporary solution through painting a border with Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero). However, I think that more beautiful solution exists. I am still open for other ideas :)